# Retrival of read names from fastq file for a particular seq

Tags: shell-script

I have a fastq file.The reads are of length 75bp.
This is how a fastq file looks like

```
@ERR030899.2391 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:4:1:16426:3738#0/1
NNCGTGTCAGTGGCCAGCAGCCCACACTGCGCATGGCTGATACTGTGGACCCCCTGGACTGGCTTTTTGGGGAGT
+
###########################################################################
@ERR030899.2392 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:4:1:16582:3744#0/1
NNAAAGTCCTGCGCTGCGGAGGACAGGAAGCACCCCCTCAATAGCCAGCACCCACAGTGAGCTGAGCACTTACAG
+
##'(''((((5/333**+)(10-11+1,,,,1/1/F<<<<FF:FFFFFF=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF#
@ERR030899.2393 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:4:1:16911:3745#0/1
NNGGATTTAGCGGGGTGATGCCTGTTGGGGGCCCGTGCCCTCCTACTTGGGGGGCAGGGGCTAGGCTGCAGAGGT
+
###########################################################################
@ERR030899.2394 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:4:1:18194:3739#0/1
NNACAAGCAATTTAGTGATAATGTCCAGAGGGCCAAGGATGCGGACCACCTTTTGCAGAACTCATATCTCGAGCA
+
##*+*)'+++FFFFFFFFFF58588==?:?FFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFF=FFFFFFFFFFFFFF6=??;
```

I have a small nucleotide sequence of around 30bp.

Lets say this is my nucleotide seq

> CTGTTGGGGGCCCGTGC

What I want to do is search for this sequence in the fastq file and extract the corresponding read name in which the sequence exists. 
So the read name in this case would be

> @ERR030899.2393 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:4:1:16911:3745#0/1

Also I want to allow a mismatch rate of 1 in the sequence.

Any script or command line ?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with fastq, please provide a small sample of input data, and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: @glenn : i added the format, let me know if you still don't get it Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v seq="CTGTTGGGGGCCCGTGC" '
  NR%4 == 1 {name = $0}
  NR%4 == 2 && index($0, seq) {print name}
' filename
```

If, by "mismatch rate of 1", you want to be able to match any 29 out of those 30 (such as `CTG.TGGGGGCCCGTGC`, that's quite a bit more complex.

...

Eh, not that much more complex:

```
awk -v seq="CTGTTGGGGGCCCGTGC" '
  NR%4 == 1 {name=$0}
  NR%4 == 2 {
    if (index($0, seq))
      print "found seq \"" seq "\" in " name
    else
      for (i=1; i<=length(seq); i++) {
        patt = substr(seq, 1, i-1) "." substr(seq, i+1)
        if (match($0, patt)) {
          print "found pattern \"" patt "\" in " name
          break
        }
      }
  }
' filename
```

Comment: This works i might ask you further development in the code once i understand it. Thanks